# How to install correct AMD drivers?

Tags: release-freya, graphic-drivers, system, kernel, updates

I've recently installed **elementary OS Freya** 0.3 on an laptop, but it doesn't run as smooth as on my desktop PC. It's sluggish while opening windows and especially switching pages in the application menu. I think that it could be a problem related to **drivers**, so I've **tried installing ATI drivers** from the software center and even from the AMD website, but at the next reboot there is only a black screen. I've **done all software updates** and also **tried installing the 3.19 kernel**, but it boots to a black screen again. How can I solve this? Is there any compatible driver?

(CPU is an **AMD APU A-micro 6400 T** quad-core)

Comment: Just to be clear, "I've installed drivers from the software center" means you've went into the "Additional Drivers" tab and installed from there?

Comment: on black screen just press insert key and display will show picture... thats drives me out whole crazy until i suddenly discovered that just any key would bring picture at display. Cheers.

Comment: @Blez, are you still having this localized issue or was it fixed in a later release? Not sure it can get more official than the official proprietary drivers. Try the steps at [this answer](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/8329/5565)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

*I do not have an AMD graphics card installed, however I found this post that details AMD, Nvidia and Intel graphics.*

[Install AMD, Nvidia and Intel graphics](http://forlearning.com/graphic-drivers-for-elementary-os/)

About the middle of the page shows how to install the AMD drivers needed.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

You can use command: `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem when you get boot screen press

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> then
2. uninstall fglrx

and if it gives error then force it by typing `-force`. It will solve your problem.

Comment: Wouldn't this just delete the AMD's proprietary driver? If so, he'll just be using open source drivers again. That doesn't seem like an answer to this question to me.