# Screen tearing when logging from hibernate or suspend

Tags: release-loki, graphic-drivers, greeter, graphics, nvidia

I have elementary OS Loki (0.4) and my computer has strange behavior when I log back from hibernation or suspend. Here is a picture of what is going on.

I would like to add that I never hibernate my computer until after I have installed NVIDIA drivers.

[image]

```
Nvidia version: 361.45.18 from ubuntu graphic ppa
CPU Intel I7 4790K
GPU GTX980
RAM 4x4GB Corsair 1600Mhz ddr3
SSD 120GB Samsung Evo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the graphics issues are only happening in your desktop background, I had the same issue and resolved it by upgrading to `nvidia-370`. [The directions to do that are covered in another question.](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/8329/5565)